# React Bootstrap Layout in Navbar

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

is there anyway to configure layout inside nav / navbar ?

i want to divide a 3 cols with the same size

[image]what i expected should be look like this
[image]

Here's my code

```js
<Navbar fixed="bottom" bg="light" variant="light">
  <Container>
   <Row>
    <Nav>
      <Col sm>
        <Nav.Link href="/communities">Browse Communities</Nav.Link>
      </Col>
      <Col sm >
        <Nav.Link href="/tasks">Tasks</Nav.Link>
      </Col>
      <Col sm>
        <Nav.Link href="/profile">Profile</Nav.Link> 
      </Col>
    </Nav>
   </Row>
  </Container>
</Navbar>
```

Comment: where did the "browse" come from  in picture ?

Comment: its browse communities 
somehow the the browse and communities got split up

Comment: I think  , it is about your browser or device width size. ?  
Where do you try ? 
What width?

Comment: firefox, with 1920 width

Comment: in your css file , did you manipulate navbar or container ?

Comment: nope i didnt manipulate built-in bootstrap class

Comment: can you share your css file and html file ?

Comment: its a jsx and i dont use css yet until its fixed
here's the file: https://pastebin.com/CSrQjX9h

Comment: it can't opened

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/CSrQjX9h what about this

Comment: not opened again

Comment: Instead of a pastebin of relevant, static code (which should shared here in your post anyway), it may be easier to just try and create a minimal codesandbox that reproduces your issue. The syntax provided in answers is correct, so if they aren't working then my guess is you've either not imported the bootstrap CSS file, somehow overridden the bootstrap CSS styles, or haven't implemented the column sizing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The columns align to a 12-column [grid system](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/layout/grid/) (*uses flexbox*), so if you want 3 columns to span the entire grid then each needs to "occupy" 4 columns.

[React-Bootstrap Col](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/layout/grid/#col-props)

```
<Navbar fixed="bottom" bg="light" variant="light">
  <Container>
   <Row>
    <Nav>
      <Col sm={4}>
        <Nav.Link href="/communities">Browse Communities</Nav.Link>
      </Col>
      <Col sm={4}>
        <Nav.Link href="/tasks">Tasks</Nav.Link>
      </Col>
      <Col sm={4}>
        <Nav.Link href="/profile">Profile</Nav.Link> 
      </Col>
    </Nav>
   </Row>
  </Container>
</Navbar>
```

Comment: @bren Hmmm, sorry about that, perhaps I found old docs, [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/layout/grid/#col-props) says the propType accepts numbers, not strings. Did you happen to see any propType warnings?

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this way:
<Navbar fixed="bottom" bg="light" variant="light">
  <Container>
   <Row>
    <Nav>
      <Col sm={8}>
        <Nav.Link href="/communities">Browse Communities</Nav.Link>
      </Col>
      <Col sm={8}>
        <Nav.Link href="/tasks">Tasks</Nav.Link>
      </Col>
      <Col sm={8}>
        <Nav.Link href="/profile">Profile</Nav.Link> 
      </Col>
    </Nav>
   </Row>
  </Container>
</Navbar>
```